# Problem quantifying the number of pixels of a certain colour in python using PIL

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I would like to print onscreen the number of red and green pixels in all the images of a given folder (code attached below).

However, it appears to be iterating over and over again, resulting in the following output: red=675, green=1036, repeated over 200 times.

Where have I gone wrong? (P.S. I am quite a newcomer to coding)

```
import os 
inputdir = r'C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\Processed_Frames\LMT_T3_2mice_nothing - Copy\2dig'

from PIL import Image


for file in os.listdir(inputdir):
    im = Image.open('000013.png')
red = 0
green = 0

for pixel in im.getdata():
    if pixel == (255, 0, 0, 255): # if your image is RGB (if RGBA, (0, 0, 0, 255) or so
        red += 1
    if pixel == (000, 128, 000, 255): # if your image is RGB (if RGBA, (0, 0, 0, 255) or so
        green += 1
    print('red=' + str(red)+', green='+str(green))
end
```

Comment: This is odd. What colour is a pixel with rgb(254,0,0)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indentations matter in python! You have the print command appear after every pixel, instead of after every image. You also don't need "end" after for loops in python. This code will print the total red and green pixels per image:

```
import os 
inputdir = r'C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\Processed_Frames\LMT_T3_2mice_nothing - Copy\2dig'

from PIL import Image


for file in os.listdir(inputdir):
    im = Image.open('000013.png')
    red = 0
    green = 0

    for pixel in im.getdata():
        if pixel == (255, 0, 0, 255): # if your image is RGB (if RGBA, (0, 0, 0, 255) or so
            red += 1
        if pixel == (000, 128, 000, 255): # if your image is RGB (if RGBA, (0, 0, 0, 255) or so
            green += 1
    print('red=' + str(red)+', green='+str(green))
```